# Created a program using emu8086 that ask a user for a response from 1-4, but only response 1 and 2 work.

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, emu8086

For a school project, I was told to create a program that asks a user two questions and each question has multiple choices. For the initial question, I ask the user to select a choice from 1 to 4, but the third and fourth choice do not work. If anyone knows how to fix this problem, I would really appreciate knowing why this is happening.

```
    BeerSelection db 'Please choose a style of beer?',0Dh,0Ah,0Ah,'Press 1 for IPA, 2 for Wheat Beer, 3 for Dark Lager, or 4 for Brown Ale.',0Dh,0Ah,0Ah,'$'
    BeerChoice db 'Which beer would you like?',0Dh,0Ah,0Ah,'Press 1 for the first beer and 2 for the second beer',0Dh,0Ah,0Ah,'$'
    Inputs db 00h,00h,
    Searching db 'Pouring Your Beer Selection...',0Ah,0Ah,0Dh,'$'
    DogfishHead db 'Pouring 60 Minute from Dogfish Head.','$'
    TreeHouse db 'Pouring Julius from Tree House Brewing Company.','$'
    BlueMoon db 'Pouring Belgiun Wheat from Blue Moon.','$'
    FunkyBuddha db 'Pouring Floridian Hefeweizen from Funky Buddha.','$'
    Metropolitan db 'Pouring Magnetron Black Lager from Metropolitan Brewing.','$'
    Yuengling db 'Pouring Traditional Lager from Yuengling.','$'
    CigarCity db 'Pouring Maduro from Cigar City.','$'
    LostCoast db 'Pouring Raspberry Brown Ale from Lost Coast Brewery.','$'
    Dispensing db 0Ah,0Ah,0Dh,'Prost!','$'

    .code

    ;start of main program

    CALL MYTITLEPAGE

    Call GETINPUTS

    MOV AH,09h; Prompt pouring beer
    MOV DX,offset Searching
    INT 21h

    ;Decision Tree 
    BeerTypes: MOV AL,Inputs[0] 
        CMP AL,01h
        JE IPA
        JMP Wheat
        JMP Lager
        JMP Ale
IPA:   MOV AL,Inputs[1]
        CMP AL,01h
        JE IPABeer1
        CMP AL,02h
        JE IPABeer2
Wheat:   MOV AL,Inputs[1]
        CMP AL,01h
        JE WheatBeer1
        CMP AL,02h
        JE WheatBeer2
Lager:   MOV AL,Inputs[1]
        CMP AL,01h
        JE LagerBeer1
        CMP AL,02h
        JE LagerBeer2
Ale:   MOV AL,Inputs[1]
        CMP AL,01h
        JE AleBeer1
        CMP AL,02h
        JE AleBeer2
```

Comment: `JMP Wheat
        JMP Lager
        JMP Ale` won't work. It will only reach the first one. You should step through with the debugger and watch where things branch. This should be easy to debug for you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's presume that the `Call GETINPUTS` gives valid choices in both `Inputs[0]` (1, 2, 3, or 4) and `Inputs[1]` (1 or 2).

The naive approach would be to test for each case like in next snippet:

```
BeerTypes:
    mov     al, Inputs[0]  ;Values are in [1,4]
    cmp     al, 1
    je      IPA
    cmp     al, 2
    je      Wheat
    cmp     al, 3
    je      Lager
    cmp     al, 4
    je      Ale
```

Given that the values are known to be in the range [1,4], the 4th comparison is not needed since it will always jump. You can replace the pair `cmp al, 4` `je Ale` with a simple `jmp Ale`.

Now we can reduce the number of comparisons even further by investigating more than just the Zero Flag (testing for equality). If, when comparing with the value 2, you find that the Carry Flag is set, then you know that the value in `AL` was below 2. This way you can omit the `cmp al, 1` instruction.

```
BeerTypes:
    mov     al, Inputs[0]  ;Values are in [1,4]
    cmp     al, 2
    jb      IPA            ;AL=1
    je      Wheat          ;AL=2
    cmp     al, 3
    je      Lager          ;AL=3
    jmp     Ale            ;AL=4
```

---

> ```
> IPA:
>     MOV AL,Inputs[1]
>     CMP AL,01h
>     JE IPABeer1
>     CMP AL,02h
>     JE IPABeer2
> Wheat:
>     MOV AL,Inputs[1]
>     CMP AL,01h
> ```

Given that the values are known to be in the range [1,2], you can replace the pair `cmp al, 2` `je IPABeer2` with a simple `jmp IPABeer2`. Same for *Wheat*, *Lager*, and *Ale*.

```
IPA:
    mov     al, Inputs[1]
    cmp     al, 1
    je      IPABeer1
    jmp     IPABeer2
Wheat:
```

### ------------------------------------------------------------

If it's possible for `Call GETINPUTS` to return more than the valid choices, then you need to guard against this by writing defensive code especially avoiding to fall through in the beneath code.

```
BeerTypes:
    mov     al, Inputs[0]  ;Values could be anything
    dec     al             ;[1,4] -> [0,3]
    cmp     al, 1
    jb      IPA            ;Inputs[0]=1
    je      Wheat          ;Inputs[0]=2
    cmp     al, 3
    jb      Lager          ;Inputs[0]=3
    je      Ale            ;Inputs[0]=4
    jmp     InputError
IPA:
    mov     al, Inputs[1]  ;Values could be anything
    dec     al             ;[1,2] -> [0,1]
    cmp     al, 1
    jb      IPABeer1       ;Inputs[1]=1
    je      IPABeer2       ;Inputs[1]=2
    jmp     InputError
Wheat:
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    CMP AL,01h
```

The [`CMP` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_35.html) will calculate subtraction (`temp = AL - 1`), in the exactly same way as [`SUB` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_308.html), but the result value is discarded (not stored anywhere, in this case `AL` remains intact), and only flags are updated.

```
    JE IPA
```

[`JE` is acronym of "jump equal"](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_146.html), which internally works as "jump when ZeroFlag is set". And `JZ` instruction is the same one, the `JE` is just its alias for better semantic reading of source, showing intent of programmer more accurately, like in this case you want to jump because `AL` was equal to `1`, not because there was some zero involved (although there was, because `1 - 1 = 0`). In case this would be some count-down loop with early exit after zero is reached in counter, then `jz` alias is more accurate for source reader.

```
    JMP Wheat
```

[`JMP`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_147.html) will take a jump no matter what. Even when `AL` contains 2, 3 or 4.

```
    JMP Lager
    JMP Ale
```

These two are unreachable piece of code.

So if you want jump to `Ale` for `AL` containing value 4, you can do similar test like for first one:

```
    CMP AL,4
    JE Ale
```

You can fix all those `jmp` to be `cmp+je`, and add after last `JE Ale` another code reporting invalid input value (outside of 1..4 range). Or just use `jmp Ale` for last one without `cmp`, so it will do that for any-other-input.